# How to use RequestQueue without a Context

Tags: java, android, request, android-volley

I am trying to test run a separate java file using Volley to send a post request. This should be simple if I can just add the request to RequestQueue if I can initialize it. There is no Context passing into this class as I am trying to test the function independently from the app. Are there any way I can go around this or any alternative way? (any class similar to RequestQueue without Context param)

```
protected static void doSomething(String name) {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(*/need Context here*/);
    StringRequest x = ...
    queue.add(x);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name= "testing";
    doSomething(name);
}
```